# Any command from KOMA-Script to set part title and partnumber in one line?

Tags: indentation, koma-script, parts

Is there any command from KOMA-Script to set the part title and partnumber in one line and if the title is long enough to get wrapped, indentation would be applied to the second line (align with the first line of the title)? It looks like:

## PART I   Very very very very very very very very very very very very _______this very very very long title line

Well the ________ indicates space i.e. indentation in front of "this".

Below the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\part{Lorem}
\section{ipsum3}
\subsection{dolor}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

And if there is no command from KOMA-Script available, how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\RedeclareSectionCommand` you only have to change the `style` key to `style=section` and to set `indention=0pt` for `part`. Additionally you have to redefine `partformat` to insert a space between the part number and the title:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{part}
\renewcommand\partformat{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{part}
\renewcommand\partformat{\partname~\thepart\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}
\part{Lorem}
\section{ipsum3}
\subsection{dolor}
\lipsum[1]
\part{Very very very very very long title line}
\section{ipsum3}
\subsection{dolor}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I copied the definition of `section` in `scrartcl.cls` and added it to a redeclaration of the `\part` sectioning command:

```
\makeatletter
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=0,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocindent=0pt,%
  tocnumwidth=1.5em%
  ]{part}
\makeatother
```

See the [KOMA-Script guide](http://texdoc.net/pkg/scrguien), chapter 21, pp. 359ss.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=0,%
  indent=\z@,%
  beforeskip=-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex,%
  afterskip=2.3ex \@plus.2ex,%
  tocindent=0pt,%
  tocnumwidth=1.5em%
  ]{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Very very very very very very very very very very very very this very very very long title line}
\section{ipsum3}
\subsection{dolor}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image: minimal working example screenshot]

Comment: Yes, that does the trick :) And also thanks a lot for the explanation with detailed info. It makes things really clearly!

Comment: Just one more thing, how could I and one space between the number and title? It seems that there is one space by section...

Comment: [esdd's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262005/5872) already addresses that. you should accept that over mine.

Comment: Yes, just done it. Still thanks for the tips!